# MySQL stored procedure always getting empty values

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am very new to stored procedure. I am trying to write a very basic stored procedure. And here it is:

```
DELIMITER //

    CREATE PROCEDURE `getname` (IN a_id INT, OUT a_name VARCHAR(50))

    BEGIN
         SELECT name INTO a_name FROM tblname WHERE id = a_id;
    END //

DELIMITER ;
```

I have a very very simple database with a single table, a single rows in it with id 1 and a string value as name. Each time I call the procedure like:

```
CALL getname(1, @a_name);
SELECT @a_name;
```

it always returns NULL values :(

I am sitting for last 4 hours with this simple problem but still no luck. Hope to get a solution from you guys.

BTW, I am using XAMPP 1.7.1 for windows 32 bit with MySQL version is 5.1.33.

Comment: Hello, I tested your code in 5.1.28 and it works properly as expected. Are you sure you have a record with id=1 and name which is not null in your table?

Answer (score 0):

Try in this session -

```
CALL getname(1, @a_name);
SELECT @a_name;

SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id = 1; -- Is there any result?
```

If result is not empty, then try to run this SELECT statement from the procedure -

```
...
BEGIN
  SELECT * FROM tblname WHERE id = 1;
END//
...
```

And call it again.